# How do you insert erb absolute paths in each html.erb file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I want to make the rendered html known about what erb files were rendered like below for debugging use in development in Rails.

```
<html>
  <!-- /RAILS_ROOT/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb -->

  <body>
    <!-- /RAILS_ROOT/app/views/entries/index.html.erb -->
    <h2>hello</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

For now, I am enforced to insert one line comment onto each erb file as below, but the work is not DRY and very painful.

```
<!-- <%= __FILE__ if Rails.env.development? %> -->
```

**My Questions are:**

1. Does any gem support this issue?
2. If 1 is no or not good enough, can you insert the comment by monkey-patching the Rails code?

Comment: Your server log tells you what was rendered (not in a very readable fashion, I agree). I can find lines like `Rendered layouts/_menubar.html.haml (30.7ms)` in my development server's log. It is not answering your question but it's giving you a different way to find the information you want

Comment: I just thought of this, you may be able to re-write the `render` method, append a line displaying the view's path and then call the "reguler" `render` method

Comment: @MrYoshiji I know #{environment}.log should work. However, when I see some tag(such as a tag or span tag) in html, I can see which html.erb renders the tag easily by this comment.

Comment: You might want to try [Railspanel](https://github.com/dejan/rails_panel) - it won't show you exactly what view renders what chunk of HTML but it will show you the render tree. Usually from there its pretty trivial to find the correct file unless you are insanely messy.

Answer (score 0):

`That’s how you go from page to page.

In plain HTML, you create a link like this:

```
<a href="/ruby-book">Improve Your Ruby Skills</a>
```

But in Rails that would look like this:(html.erg)

<%= link_to "Improve Your Ruby Skills", "/ruby-book" %>